# Can't ping host osx from guest Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: network, wifi, unix, virtualbox

I created an Ubuntu-16.04 VM via VirtualBox on my osx machine. I'm using 2 network adapters: `Bridged Adapter [en0: Wi-Fi (Airport)]` and `Host-only Adapter (vboxnet0)`.

This is the ifconfig o/p from the 2 machines, osx first:

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 3c:15:c2:c8:27:d0
    inet 192.168.0.12 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 3e:15:c2:8c:a2:00
    Configuration:
            id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
            maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
            root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
            ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
vboxnet0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00
    inet 192.168.56.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

Ubuntu next:

```
$ ifconfig
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:7a:ba:0d
          inet addr:192.168.0.26  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f296:f0:610e:2b37/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6174 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4228 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:7159986 (7.1 MB)  TX bytes:456256 (456.2 KB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:b6:c9:6e
          inet addr:192.168.56.101  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba63:3f0e:321:ee37/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:75 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:26827 (26.8 KB)  TX bytes:9002 (9.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:583 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:583 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:79319 (79.3 KB)  TX bytes:79319 (79.3 KB)
```

I'm unable to ping osx from ubuntu:

```
$ ping 192.168.0.12
PING 192.168.0.12 (192.168.0.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.0.12 ping statistics ---
480 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 490401ms
```

But I can ping ubuntu (guest) from osx. How can I fix this?

`Note: Firewall is disabled on both the machines`

Comment: Is virtual box configured to bridge or NAT the guest os? Seems you want bridged for a network where pings work between peer OS.

Comment: Also, this might help a bunch of people - any objection to undeleting it.

Comment: I'm using bridge and host-only adapters. I mentioned it in the question, " I'm using 2 network adapters: Bridged Adapter [en0: Wi-Fi (Airport)] and Host-only Adapter (vboxnet0)"

Comment: duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/837464/cant-ping-host-osx-from-guest-ubuntu-16-04